# Kubernetes set only container resources limits implies same values for resources requests

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod with only one container that have this resources configuration:

`resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 1000m
    memory: 1000Mi`

From the node where the pod is scheduled I read this:

`CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits
1 (50%)       1 (50%)     1000Mi (12%)     1000Mi (12%)`

Why the "resources requests" are setted when I dont' want that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Container’s request is set to match its limit regardless if there is a default memory request for the namespace.([Kubernetes Doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-default-namespace/#what-if-you-specify-a-container-s-limit-but-not-its-request))